# Приоритет перегрузки операторов

Tags: c++, ооп

Почему перегрузка операторов через методы класса приоритетней чем через функции?

Answer (score 3):

Из за области видимости. Более локальное (метод класса) затеняет более глобальное (отдельная функция)